# online image focus detection or app

Tags: focus, web

I am wondering if anyone knows of an online image focus detector programme that will detect that the image is in focus without having to painstakingly go through and printing all images. I have uploaded some images to sell on a shop site but I am worried that some maybe out of focus when customers print them out after enlarging. Some of my images were scanned but they have been mixed up with  others that were photographed, so need to check they are sharp and in focus. I have used FastRaw Viewer that detects edges that are sharp, but does anyone know of another way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I understand the question, you are uploading images to sell without first visually inspecting them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can software auto-detect image focus?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7354/can-software-auto-detect-image-focus)

Comment: The duplicate does not cover the online part, but scraping/downloading all the images from the online store to be able to detect the image focus off-line is more of a scripting question rather than photography (I think).
This other question might also be relevant: https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/32388/9161